# Java FTP client not downloading file

Tags: java, ftp

I was trying to download a zip file from server using FTPClient my code for download is

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPConnection().makeConnection(loc);

        try {
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            success = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(PATH + preset + "/" + file_to_download + offset);
            System.out.println("Download Path:-" + PATH + preset + "/" + file_to_download + offset);
            if (!success) {
                System.out.println("Could not changed the directory to RIBS");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Directory changed to RIBS");
            }
            FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();
            for (FTPFile file : files) {
                if (file.getName().contains(".zip")) {
                    dfile = file;
                }

            }
            fsize=dfile.getSize();
            fileMap.put("build", dfile.getName());
            primaryStage = (Stage) ap.getScene().getWindow();

            String homePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
            File downloadPath = new File(homePath + "\\Buildss\\" + osVer);
            if (!downloadPath.exists()) {
                if (downloadPath.mkdirs()) {
                    System.out.println("Directory is created!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
                }
            }
            // System.out.println(chosenDir.getAbsolutePath());
            filePath = new File(downloadPath + "/" + dfile.getName());
            if (filePath.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File altready exist");
                return;
            }
            else {
                fileMap.put("path", filePath.toString());
                fileMap.put("kind", "RIBS");


                Task downloadTask = new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() throws IOException {
                        try {
                            long len = dfile.getSize();
                            System.out.println("File From Server:::::: " + len);
                             downloadFile = new File(downloadPath + "/" + dfile);
                            outputFile = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ftpClient.sendNoOp();
                        ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(1000);
                        //ftpClient.retrieveFile(dfile, output);
                     if (ftpClient.retrieveFile(dfile.getName(), outputFile) == true) {
                            downloadButton.setDisable(true);
                            System.out.println("LOCAL FILE LENGTH:-" + downloadFile.length());

                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                Thread t = new Thread(downloadTask);
                t.start();
```

but now if I go the the download location I see something like this "-rwxrwx---    1 ftp      ftp      513235293 Apr 11 06" but no file is downloaded.
this code was working file couple of days back.

Comment: After `retrieveFile()` call, you may want to call `getReplyCode()` to check the reply code of last FTP reply. It will give you more info.

Comment: the reply code is 226 which says "A 226 reply code is sent by the server before closing the data connection after successfully processing the previous client command affecting the data connection. In most cases, it signals the completion of a file transfer"

Comment: Can you add the output (sys out) statements as well? I would also sysout `downloadFile` object just to see where it's writing.

Comment: ooh thanks , it should be downloadFile = new File(downloadPath + "/" + dfile.getName());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is related to following

```
// File dfile
FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();
for (FTPFile file : files) {
    if (file.getName().contains(".zip")) {
    dfile = file;
    }
}
...
File downloadPath = new File(homePath + "\\Buildss\\" + osVer);
...
// File downloadFile;
downloadFile = new File(downloadPath + "/" + dfile);
```

I assume `dfile` referred to a `File` object representing a Unix file. So the concatenation of `downloadPath + "/" + dfile` does not return what you expect.

You should rather use `downloadPath.getName() + "/" + dfile.getName()`. But you need to strip a possible pathname from `dfile.getName()`. The prefered way would be to use [java.nio.file.Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) objects instead.